# two spyder IDEs in one system and also shows missing dependencies

Tags: python, python3, versions, ide, spyder

one is default spyder3 from snap store and one is the updated version named spyder of spyder5.0.3

```
:~$ pip install update spyder-kernels==2.0.1
Defaulting to user installation because normal site-packages is not writeable
Requirement already satisfied: update in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (0.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: spyder-kernels==2.0.1 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (2.0.1)
Requirement already satisfied: pyzmq>=17 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from spyder-kernels==2.0.1) (18.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: ipykernel>=5.3.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from spyder-kernels==2.0.1) (5.5.5)
Requirement already satisfied: jupyter-client>=5.3.4 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from spyder-kernels==2.0.1) (6.1.2)
Requirement already satisfied: decorator<5 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from spyder-kernels==2.0.1) (4.4.2)
Requirement already satisfied: ipython>=7.6.0 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from spyder-kernels==2.0.1) (7.13.0)
Requirement already satisfied: cloudpickle in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from spyder-kernels==2.0.1) (1.3.0)
Requirement already satisfied: wurlitzer>=1.0.3 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from spyder-kernels==2.0.1) (2.1.0)
Requirement already satisfied: tornado>=4.2 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from ipykernel>=5.3.0->spyder-kernels==2.0.1) (5.1.1)
Requirement already satisfied: traitlets>=4.1.0 in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from ipykernel>=5.3.0->spyder-kernels==2.0.1) (4.3.3)
Requirement already satisfied: pexpect in /usr/lib/python3/dist-packages (from ipython>=7.6.0->spyder-kernels==2.0.1) (4.6.0)
Requirement already satisfied: style==1.1.0 in ./.local/lib/python3.8/site-packages (from update) (1.1.0)
```

Comment: Please add output from `snap list | grep -i spyder; dpkg -l | grep -i spyder; pip freeze | grep -i spyder ; pip3 freeze | grep -i spyder; which spyder; which spyder3; which spyder5 ` to the question by editing it